# Google Maps API rectangle bounds_changed event firing on resize and move

Tags: google-maps

I am working with the GoogleMaps API and I'm trying to distinguish between a rectangle object being resized or moved.

I am using the listener like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

However, this will fire when the rectangle is resized AND when it is moved completely. Is there some way to distinguish between these two distinct events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the bounds of the rectangle initially, when the event fires check if both(soutWest  and NorthEast) have been changed. When It does , the rectangle has been moved, otherwise it has been resized.

After the check update the stored bounds.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the way @Darwin has suggested. When we just begin to drag the coordinates still remain the same and so the event is fired for `drag` as well as `bounds_changed`

An easier and more reliable way, I did is to have a global variable called `isBeingDragged` and set it to `true` in `dragstart` event handler. In the `bounds_changed` event handler, I checked if this variable is `true`. If it is not, its a resize event, else it is a drag event.

I again set the `isBeingDragged` variable to false in `drag_end` event handler.